# JBDC - execute SELECT and INSERT atomically across concurrent threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have searched the web for simple examples to this but to no avail.  I need to run a `select` and `insert` operation as an atomic unit in Java, using JDBC against an Oracle database.

Effectively I need to do the following:

1. Select code from users
2. Go through all codes until I find one that is not used (as users can be deleted there may be codes available in the middle of the range)
3. Insert new user with that available code

This is a simple operation normally, but as my application is multi-threaded I'm not sure how to go about this.  As concurrent threads running at the same time could both try and insert using the same value for code.

There are a couple workarounds or hacks that I can think of to do the job but in general how can I lock the table to make this operation atomic?  Most of what I've seen involves row locks but as I'm not updating I don't see how this applies.

Comment: Why don't you use "insert select" way. I m not sure whether it works for your requirement since I am not aware of the table structures. but I think if you could make select in such a way that it will be used in insert then your problems will be solved.

Comment: Hi. I don't think this will work. My table structure is basically like. id,code,name and say the data is 1,1,John;2,2,Frank;4,4,Bob So I want to do a select to discover that code 3 is not used and then do an insert values (5,3,Bill) with concurrency multiple threads might could get 3 as the next available code and the 2nd thread will fail when it tries to insert if the select and insert is not atomic

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough problem to do entirely in SQL.  Any solution is going to have race condition problems.  If I was going to do it entirely in SQL I'd use a deleted code table.  When users then get deleted you'd use some service to add their code to the deleted table.  If the deleted code table is empty threads would use a sequence number to get their new code.  Getting a code from the deleted would need to be in a `synchronized` block because of the get and then set nature with multiple SQL operations.  I don't think SQL transactions are going to help there.  They may keep the data consistent but if two threads use the same code then one of the two commits is going to throw an exception.

I think a better, and faster, mechanism would be to have a separate thread manage these deleted codes.  It could write it in a database but also keep a `BlockingQueue` of deleted codes for the other threads to consume.  If there must be no holes and you are worried about crashing then it will need to validate the list of available holes by querying the user table at launch.  It would not need to synchronize or do any SQL transactions because only it would be deleting from the deleted code table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps there should be a table of all "codes" which has a boolean allocated field. Then acquiring a code would be an "update code set allocated = true where code = (select min(code) from codes where allocated = false) returning code into ...".  If the codes have meaning, then maybe they should be listed. If they don't have meaning, then there shouldn't really be a worry about gaps...

Comment: Thanks @Glenn.  I'm not sure how you get the `code` result out of that statement but something like that would work.  Even with it the threads are going to be looping until they update the row.  I still think an allocator thread is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would lean toward putting the logic in a stored procedure. Use "select for update" to lock, then commit to unlock.

You can add a filter to your insert statement and retry logic on the client end, I guess:

- determine an available code (proposed code)
- perform the insert with a filter determine the number of rows from the executeUpdate result (0   means a concurrent thread grabbed this code, try again)

The insert would look something along these lines where 3 is your new id, 'Joe' your new user, and proposedCode the one you think is available:

```
INSERT INTO users
  SELECT 3, :proposedCode, 'Joe' 
    FROM dual
    WHERE :proposedCode NOT IN (SELECT code FROM users)
```

Comment: I think, You can use updatable ResultSet if you intend to do the logic at Java side only. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Naved Honestly, I don't know. It's been a few years since I tried that. I would typically put this kind of logic into a stored procedure. That way, an api can be made available for any type of client without the client needing to worry about the implementation details (and without the server side worrying about how a client may try to implement). For a CRUD type of app, I would put a version field on the table, do the read, and later, when writing the modified record back, add a "WHERE version = <loaded version>". If no rows were updated, msg a concurrent updated failure to the user.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
insert into usertable (
  id, 
  code, 
  name
) values (
  user_id_sequence.nextval,
  (
      select min(newcode) 
        from usertable, (
           select level newcode 
             from dual 
          connect by level <= (select max(code)+1 from usertable))
       where not exists (select 1 from usertable where code = newcode)
  ),
  'mynewusername'
)
```

EDIT:

changed to max(code) + 1, so if there is no gap available, there is a new code available.